# Calling the becomeDirty action no longer seems to set hasDirtyAttributes

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have updated to the latest 3.x version of Ember and have got ember-data version 3.28.7. In older versions of Ember (3.20) calling the becomeDirty action on a model set hasDirtyAttributes to true on that model, but in 3.28.7 of ember-data observers that monitor hasDirtyAttributes on a list of models are triggered, but the actual value of hasDirtyAttributes in the model seems to be false.

Has anyone else seen this? I cannot find any links to people having this same issue?

I should say I am using classic Ember objects: `Model.extend({})`

I get the following results with the following commands:

```
model.hasDirtyAttributes // false
model._internalModel.currentState.isDirty // true
```

Looking in @ember-data, it looks like when getting the @tagged currentState it returns this.___recordState instead of the this._internalModel.currentState because CUSTOM_MODEL_CLASS is defined? (Whatever that means.) Anyway the result of the state object thing seems to be false:

```
model.___recordState.isDirty // false
```

Why isn't that set to true? Investigating more...

It looks like a lot of things called canary-features have been enabled. In the old version of @ember-data a configuration file looked like:

```
export default {
  SAMPLE_FEATURE_FLAG: null,
  RECORD_DATA_ERRORS: null,
  RECORD_DATA_STATE: null,
  IDENTIFIERS: true,
  REQUEST_SERVICE: null,
  CUSTOM_MODEL_CLASS: null,
  FULL_LINKS_ON_RELATIONSHIPS: true,
};
```

but now it looks like:

```
export default {
  SAMPLE_FEATURE_FLAG: null,
  RECORD_DATA_ERRORS: true,
  RECORD_DATA_STATE: true,
  IDENTIFIERS: true,
  REQUEST_SERVICE: true,
  CUSTOM_MODEL_CLASS: true,
  FULL_LINKS_ON_RELATIONSHIPS: true,
  RECORD_ARRAY_MANAGER_IDENTIFIERS: true,
  REMOVE_RECORD_ARRAY_MANAGER_LEGACY_COMPAT: true,
};
```

And if I hardcode CUSTOM_MODEL_CLASS to be false things seem to be working again. So now I need to figure out the best way of turning this stuff off without editing node_modules files.

Anyone know if just setting CUSTOM_MODEL_CLASS to false is OK or should I turn off other things?

I have now tried multiple things to get:

`@ember-data/canary-features/addon/index.ts`

to turn off CUSTOM_MODEL_CLASS but it keeps setting it to true. I don't know much about typescript, but according to:

https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/3.28/modules/@ember-data%2Fcanary-features

I should be able to set a window variable to set which features are off. So in the index.html file (may not be best place, but can change it later) I have set:

```
    <script>
        window.EmberDataENV = {
            FEATURES: {
                CUSTOM_MODEL_CLASS: false
            }
        };
    </script>
```

above where the assets/vendor.js file gets imported, but as I said before this isn't working. Time to go to debugger...

Well I set some break points at the point where some of these features are set but they aren't hit. So how are they set!?

I guess I have three options at the moment. Downgrade to the last version of ember-data that doesn't seem to have these flags set (3.27.1) and hope things work with newer versions of Ember libraries (looks like flags were set to true in ember-data 3.28.0-beta.1 - do we think this was done by accident?), or make a build script go into the default-features.ts file and change the values, or maintain my own version of ember-data with these fields set to null...

Comment: I have created the following issue in github so will see what comes of that:

https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/7851

Comment: They won't fix the issue as it is not a part of the public API, which is disappointing. My workaround is mentioned in that issue.